# data source key tab configuration using web logic key tab

Tags: weblogic, datasource, jndi, kerberos, jaas

i need to use key tab for database authorization in web logic. my application should read database configuration from JNDI specified in web logic data. can someone please guide me what exactly need to be done for same.

Comment: what do you mean by key tab?

Answer (score -1):

I understand you're asking how to define a JNDI datasource on Weblogic. In the homepage, click "Data Sources". Set a datasource name along with a jndi name. on the next page, chose the appropriate driver. the next page is where you choose the target server for that data source. Choose the server you're working on and save. you can access that datasource in your code by its jndi name.

Comment: thanks for quick responce. i know this to set datasource. but i need not to give user name and passowrd that credential should read from keytab file.

Comment: I don't know if that's possible. sorry couldn't be of any help